# Open unique secondary window with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having a trouble when i open a secondary window. Now I'm just creating a toplevel window with a button and I need to open the same secondary window If i click the button (not generate a new instance).

Which is the better way to generate single secondary window and not generating a new window instance?

I leave the code that I'm actually working on:

```
import tkinter

class LogWindow():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(self.parent)

class MainWindow(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        frame = tkinter.Frame(self, borderwidth=1)
        frame.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.LogButton = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Log Viewer", command= self.openLogWindow)
        self.LogButton.grid(sticky=tkinter.E+tkinter.W)

        self.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH,expand=True)

    def openLogWindow(self):
        self.logWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(self.parent)
        self.app = LogWindow(self.logWindow)

def main():
    global app, stopRead
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry("300x300")
    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Maybe i need to have a single instance of a Toplevel class and call show and close to show or hide the secondary window.

Comment: What exactly troubel do you have ?

Comment: `withdraw()` to hide, `deiconify()` to show, `focus_set()` to set focus.

Comment: @furas I want to have a single instance of a secondary window that i can close and reopen again, and not generating a new one when i click open window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after some tests I've found how to solve that, thanks to the @furas response and some investigation about the Tkinter events with the protocol function.

I've got that working with:

```
import tkinter

logWindowExists = False

class LogWindow():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        global logWindowExists, root
        logWindowExists = True

        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(self.parent)

    def on_closing(self):
        global logWindowExists
        logWindowExists = False
        self.parent.destroy()

class MainWindow(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        frame = tkinter.Frame(self, borderwidth=1)
        frame.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.LogButton = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Log Viewer", command= self.openLogWindow)
        self.LogButton.grid(sticky=tkinter.E+tkinter.W)

        self.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH,expand=True)

    def openLogWindow(self):
        if not logWindowExists:
            self.logWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(self.parent)
            self.app = LogWindow(self.logWindow)
            self.logWindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.app.on_closing)
        else:
            self.logWindow.deiconify()

def main():
    global app, stopRead, root
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry("300x300")
    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Using a boolean to know if the window exists or not i can handle when the window it's opened or not and just show the existing window or creating a new one.